# How to make test running only after finishing the previous iteration

Tags: nightwatch.js

I´m running a test in a loop but when running i=2, assertions fail.
For what I can understand it starts i=3 before ending i=2.
How can I make nightwatch finish first i=2 then after start i=3 and only start i=4 after finishing i=3 and so on.

```
     .execute(function () {
           return document.querySelectorAll('.wrap>section:nth-of-type(2)>.tsr-container a').length
                    },
                    function (result) {
                        total_downL = result.value;
                        console.log("Number of download buttons i: " + total_downL);
                        for (i = 1; i <= total_downL; i++) {
                            this.waitForElementVisible('.wrap>section:nth-of-type(2)>.tsr-container a.tsr-module-product:nth-child(' + i + ') button.btnDownload', 2000, true,
                                function (result) {
                                    this.click('.btnDownload')
                                    .pause(3000)
                                    .windowHandles(function (result) {
                                        var handle = result.value[1];
                                        browser.switchWindow(handle);
                                        browser.pause(5000);
                                    })
                                    .assert.elementPresent('.modal-title')
                                    .click('.close');
```

Comment: Don't use a loop. Use a recursive function.

Comment: @FlorentB., I´ve posted the code, I want to count the number of elements and use it as the superior limit. Can you please an example of recursive function?